# How can I close all projects in an Eclipse workspace while eclipse is closed?

Tags: eclipse

I have a problem with one of my workspaces; if I start eclipse with all of the projects open, eclipse might take 20 minutes to even reach the point where it's even responsive, if not longer.

Is it possible to start eclipse in "safe mode", where none of the projects are open and plugins are disabled, so that I can get my workspace in order?

Comment: Have you tried to increase the heap size available to Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, it's already at 1.5GB, and that doesn't solve the underlying problem.

Comment: Wow 1.5 GB is a lot!! There is a option that I usually use for bigger projects, which is to disable automatic builds in order to avoid long waiting times at startup or while implementing new stuff. For this kind of projects I prefer to build them manually. But besides this, I do not know any other option.

Comment: Use a different workspace and import the project that you actually want.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have not found the piece of metadata that says whether or not a project is closed, I suspect it is not possible through that route as I have grepped through the files created and not found one.

I have 2 workarounds, the first of which is:

1. Close Eclipse.
2. Rename the .project file in the top level of each project (painful to do manually
   if you have a lot, you could write a script).
3. Start Eclipse.
4. Projects should show up as closed.

Note: to undo this you will have to revert the name changes (ie turn them all back to .project files) before you try to open them.

The advantages of this approach is that you can work at getting one project behaving at a time (if this is appropriate for your needs).

The other approach is to simply create a new workspace, get that set up correctly (whatever it is you need - VCS, correct JRE, Target Platform etc) and then import each of your projects 1 (or more) at a time.

This could be more work, depending on how customised your workspace gets (perspective layouts, preferences, code templates etc), however this  would give you a clean slate. This might be best if things are truly that bad.

Note: basing all this on 3.7.1

Comment: This isn't a bad solution. The big problem is that because of memory and deadlock constraints, opening all of the problems simultaneously causes me to spin endlessly. So, if I can close a few projects manually, that could help. Thanks!

Comment: for Windows users:  windows explorer may give you problems renaming a file that starts with a dot.  for example I renamed .project to .project.bac.  Then when I tried to change it back to .project and windows explorer would not let me.  The easiest solution is to jump to the command line for the rename.

Comment: @katsharp i up-voted you for point 2) as I've got the same issue with a particular project and can't open the workspace at all (for different reasons). I also failed to find the metadata so your solution is a neat one.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on one of the open projects ---> Close unrelated projects.

It closes all projects except that one.

Comment: The problem was that I could not open eclipse. The question was "How do I do this while eclipse is closed."

Answer (score 0):

Based katsharp's answer I created 2 simple bash scripts.

On windows environment I run these from a git bash prompt.
Maxdepth is specific for my environment.

```
# close_projects.sh
for dir in $(find . -maxdepth 3 -name .project -printf '%h\n')
do
    echo mv $dir/.project $dir/closed.project
    mv $dir/.project $dir/closed.project
done
```

```
# open_projects.sh
for dir in $(find . -maxdepth 3 -name .project -printf '%h\n')
do
    echo mv $dir/.project $dir/closed.project
    mv $dir/.project $dir/closed.project
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the least painful solution is to go under

```
eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins
```

and rename or remove

```
org.eclipse.e4.workbench
```

Answer (score -2):

I havent found any such method but you can do this while eclipse is running.
Go to package Explorer ,  select all the projects then go to Project -> Close Project. This will close all the projects.So next time when you start Eclipse, it will not load all the projects and it will response earlier than before.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you earn sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. If you have a related but different question, ask a new question referencing this one if it will help provide context.

Comment: this doesn't help as the user can't realistically open the workspace.